# Increase Numpy array Dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two images, one is RGB while other is Gray Scale Image.

I have 2 Numpy Arrays holding these two images. These array look like this :

```
a = [[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ], 
    [  [7,8,9], [10,11,12] ]]
b = [ [1,2],
      [3,4] ]
```

I want to convert `b` to

```
b = [[ [1,1,1], [2,2,2] ], 
     [ [3,3,3], [4,4,4] ]]
```

And after that perform `c = a - b` and store this result as an image. How to efficiently convert `b` using numpy?

Comment: No need to fill `b` just do `c = a - b[..., None]`.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Can you explain the syntax here please.

Comment: `[..., None] means keep all axes (the'...') and add one axis at the end (the 'None') so this creates a view on `b` of shape `(2, 2, 1)`. When you subtract this from `a` the last axis gets broadcast to match that of `a`

Comment: Great. It helped a lot. Can you answer this question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48354259/subtract-2-numpy-arrays-with-condition