# Subtract 2 Numpy arrays with condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, subtraction

I have two Numpy arrays which look like this:

```
a = [[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ], 
    [  [7,8,9], [10,11,12] ]]

b = [[ [1,1,1], [0,0,0] ], 
     [ [3,3,3], [4,4,4] ]]
```

I want to perform `c = a - b` with condition that `c = 255 if b>0 else a`

So c should be like this:

```
c = [[ [255,255,255], [4,5,6] ], 
     [ [255,255,255], [255,255,255] ]]
```

How to do it efficiently without any loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.where`

```
>>> c = np.where(np.array(b)>0, 255, a)
>>> c
array([[[255, 255, 255],
        [  4,   5,   6]],

       [[255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]]])
```

Btw. there is no subtracting happpening here; maybe change the title of your question.